# Taking URL with a photo from XML code and converting it

Tags: xml, bash, url, curl

I have the xml code contains the url to a photo, just like below.

```
<response>
<data>
<images>
<image>
<url>
http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m3vm93gMpy1qjc1a7o1_1280.jpg
</url>
<id>47e</id>
<source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=47e</source_url>
</image>
</images>
</data>
</response>
```

All I want is to code in bash something, that takes the url from xml code and then uses img2txt to convert it into the draw in my terminal. How can it be done?

Comment: what should be the output format?

Comment: I suppose I have to save the picture from this url to a file, essentially this is what I need

Comment: Output format can be for example jpg

Comment: `img2txt` is not for converting `jpg` to `jpg` - it's for converting images into *text-based coloured files*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete solution using **`xmlstarlet`**, **`wget`** and **`img2txt`** tools:

Assuming that input xml file named `test.xml` and the loaded image is converted with *img2txt* default output format (*ansi : coloured ANSI*).

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "normalize-space(//url)" -n test.xml | wget -i - -O /tmp/img.jpg -q
img2txt /tmp/img.jpg > tumble.txt
cat tumble.txt
```

The output (as screenshot):

[image]